# Dynamic link is not working in build of react-app

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have following route in `BrowserRouter` and `Switch`

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'          
<Router>
<Switch>
      <Route exact path="/" component={HomeScreen}/>
      <Route exact path="/about" component={AboutScreen}/>
      <Route exact path="/products" component={ProductScreen}/>
      <Route path="/product/:id" component={SingleProductScreen}/>
</Router>
</Switch>
```

All links are working perfectly in localhost. Except on the last route, nothing renders (not even 404 page) when I `npm run build` and then deploy.
I'm using react-router-dom for routing

Edit: This is what I get on my domain.com/product/1

[image]

This is my SingleProductScreen.js:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'

const SingleProductScreen = ({ match }) => {
const id = match.params.id;
return (
    <div className="App">
        <h1 className="title">{`Product Number: ${id}`}</h1>
    </div>
    )
}

export default SingleProductScreen
```

Comment: 1. Where are you deploying this to? 2. Does the host know to forward all pages to `/` because it's a single page application?

Comment: I have deployed it on firebase as well as on cPanel. My all other route works perfectly fine say my about or contact page

Comment: Can you show the whole router component?

Comment: I edited the question. Please check

Comment: Are you sure that `ProductScreen` and `SingleProductScreen` are working correctly? The router looks fine to me

Comment: In local everything is working exactly as it should

Comment: Without providing the components themselves I can't tell you any more.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228628/discussion-between-kaustubh-and-aron).

Answer (score 0):

Once you build in react it will generate all static file.

For Dynamic routing it is more like

```
const App = () => (
    <BrowserRouter>
        {/* here's a div */}
        <div>
        {/* here's a Route */}
        <Route path="/products" component={ProductScreen}/>
        </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
)

// when the url matches `/:id` this component renders
const ProductScreen= ({ match }) => (
    // here's a nested div
    <div>
        {/* here's a nested Route,
            match.url helps us make a relative path */}
        <Route
        path={match.url + '/:id'}
        component={SingleProductScreen}
        />
    </div>
)
```